# display a specific rows only, php script or sql query

Tags: php, sql

i have a table like this

```
id     tran_id     event_name
1      55262       activate
2      55262       suspended
3      47282       approval
```

what i want if it found that the event_name is equal to 'activate' don't show all the data with have the same tran_id

I've tried to get this using sql-script but i think it should use a php-script

Comment: no, do it the sql query, always good practice to save on bandwidth where possible

Comment: Why do you think it would be more appropriate to use PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE tran_id NOT IN (
    SELECT tran_id 
    FROM yourTable 
    WHERE event_name = 'activate')
```

or

```
SELECT a.*
FROM yourTable AS a
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS b ON a.tran_id = b.tran_id AND b.event_name = 'activate'
WHERE b.tran_id IS NULL
```